# Can legends be exported as image in CARTO BUILDER?

Tags: carto, export, image

How to add a legend when exporting a BUILDER map as jpg/png image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as explained in the message on the bottom left corner of your screenshot `Legends and widgest won't be exported as part of the image`. The only workaround is making a screenshot.